# Pass parameters to Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to update the document fields using the parameters passed to cloud function. I am getting an error
as
5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/react-ycce/databases/(default)/documents/papers/etc

values are passed in function, but I don't know how to put them in the query. Please help me.

```
exports.upload = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    let dept = data.dept;

    let paperRef = db.collection("papers/"+data.dept);
    console.log(paperRef);

    return paperRef.update({
        name : data.doc_name,
        dept : data.dept,
        sem : data.sem,
        course_code : data.cc,
        type : data.resources,
        url: data.resourceLink,   
    })
    .then( () =>{ return("Successfully Uploaded")}
    )
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
        return("Error while uploading");   
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the value of `"papers/"+data.dept`? Collection references must have an odd number of segments, and if `data.dept` does NOT contain a slash you will get 2 segments.

Comment: "papers" is a collection in firestore database and "dept" is the document inside it. I want to update the fields of that document. I am passing the document name from the data.dept . I want to know how to frame the path to that document.

Comment: If I pass the document name directly as db.collection("papers/ct"); the fields git updated. When I pass as a parameter, it shows error.

Comment: As I said `db.collection("papers/ct");` should normally not work: Collection references must have an odd number of segments.

Comment: On the other hand, `docRef = db.doc("papers/ct");` should work.

Comment: I want to pass the parameters. By providing string directly, it is working. While passing db.doc("papers/" + data.dept); it is showing error.

Comment: Can you show the **exact** result of `console.log(data.dept)`as Frank asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your reference with:

```
let paperRef = db.collection("papers/"+data.dept);
```

But `db.collection` returns a reference to a collection, while you're passing it the path to a document. So you should use:

```
let paperRef = db.doc("papers/"+data.dept);
```

---

If you're still getting an error after this, your `data.dept` probably doesn't contain the value you expect. I recommend adding a `console.log(data.dept)` right at the start of the query, and checking in the logging output what it prints.

Comment: Hey Frank, I did the console.log() , I am getting the data inside the  function but not able to reference that particular document. When I directly give the string as the path like "papers / ct" , it gets updated. While when I pass    "papers/" + data.dept    it gives me error 
5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/react-ycce/databases/(default)/documents/papers/ct

Comment: It sounds like the document doesn't exist, in which case you can't run an `update` call against it. To "create or update" a document, use `set` with `merge: true` as shown in the second example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document.